# Convert result from HQL into Object

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hql

This is my method in repository class :

```
@Query("select max(entry_fee) as maxBuyInFee, max(prize) as maxPrize, max(participants_number) as maxParticipants from Tournament tournament")
    FilterMaxValues findFilterMaxValues();
```

And this is my FilterMaxValues class :

```
public class FilterMaxValues {

    private Integer maxBuyInFee;

    private Integer maxPrize;

    private Integer maxParticipants;
```

How can i convert result from this HQL into FilterMaxValues object ?

Now i get :

> No converter found capable of converting from type
>   [java.util.HashMap] to type [com.test.FilterMaxValues]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) if your `FilterMaxValues` is not an entity, like

```
interface FilterMaxValues {

Integer getMaxBuyInFee();

Integer getMaxPrize();

Integer getMaxParticipants();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to annotate your `FilterMaxValues` class with `@Entity` and `@Table(name="yourDBTable")` so that `Spring` can do the conversion for you automaticaly?